# why child component styles overwriting by global css?

Tags: css, angular

I am importing a base css file in my index.html that includes width as auto, but this style is  taking priority over the style I define in components(used width as 70%) using styleUrls: ["..."]. What is the best way to make sure that my component-scoped css takes priority over styling defined the traditional way? Should I have my global styles scoped to my top level component?

Comment: please share your code.

Answer (score 8):

In general css in your component is the one that has priotiry. You can try to use

encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None in your app.component.

if you have a class in your component it would have priority.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html

Answer (score 7):

You can increase specifity of the selectors in your global css.

When you have in your `<my-comp class="some-class">`

```
.someClass {
  width: 70%;
}
```

then you can override with

```
body .some-class.some-class {
  width: 100%;
}
```

or

```
body my-comp.some-class.some-class {
  width: 100%;
}
```

What way to increase specifity of your selector works best for you depends on your specific requirements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 6):

In order to override global scss, simply add below line `(encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None)` in your *component.ts* file:

```
  @Component({  selector: 'app-custom-component',
      templateUrl: './custom-component.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./custom-component.component.scss'],
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })
```

Comment: This is not a great answer since the way angular works is it will load that component's CSS globally and never unload it even if you unload the component, I noticed this issue in a angular app I had